# Capturing Worksheet name on ActiveX button click

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table, togglebutton

I have the code below that works perfectly well. I'm simply interested in finding out if there is a better method for picking up the Worksheet name.

Scenario: I have "x" worksheets with "n" toggle buttons. Each toggle button controls data displayed in a worksheet via hidden Slicers. The data to be toggled is simply zeroes and ones, so I show/hide "1's" when the toggle button is clicked.

The code:

```
  Private Sub tgl_btn_Click()
    Set InputSheet = Worksheets("My Worksheet")
    Call do_filter("myvalue", tgl_btn.Value, "PivotTable1")   
 End Sub
```

do_filter takes the name of the toggle button, along with the value and Pivot table name to a Module which hide/unhides values in the pivot table.

So each toggle button on a worksheet has the following line included before the Module call:

```
Set InputSheet = Worksheets("My Worksheet")
```

Is there any way of picking up this worksheet name without hard coding it into the logic on every single button click?

The reason: Users rename the worksheet and therefore kill the toggle button function.

Comment: If the toggle button is on the sheet you could use `ActiveSheet` - seeing as the sheet has to be active before you can press the button.

Comment: Rather than using ActiveX buttons, try Form buttons, you can tie those all to the same sub in a normal module and use Application.Caller to determine which was pushed. This is the button object that was pushed: ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  Thanks! `Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet` works a treat. Simple really. I was getting a little too focused on returning the sheet name.

Comment: @jkpieterse Thanks. However, I do not have a toggle button in my Insert toolbox otherwise I would most probably have used it. Is there a means of adding this in the "Insert" toolbox??

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact that you are using a toggle button. Arguably toggle buttons are sometimes considered bad UI design. I can never tell what will happen when they are clicked. Perhaps a checkbox would do just as well?

Comment: @jkpieterse The users wanted something colourful to indicate which toggle buttons were pressed so the buttons turn orang-ish when selected. The buttons revert to a normal button colour when deselected. There is a group of 11 toggle buttons where users can toggle on any combination. I had considered check boxes, but users preferred the toggles! Ho hum!

Comment: I get it. NB: Assuming the code is in the codemodule behind the worksheet in question You can address the worksheet belonging to the code module with the simple keyword "Me". So Me.Range("A1") is cell A1 on the worksheet on which the ActiceX control is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The reason: Users rename the worksheet*

Yeah, users are good at breaking frail VBA code - *very* good actually!

Sometimes you can work off the `ActiveSheet` - and that's great. But other times you *do* need to get a specific worksheet, and using its `Name` leaves you with the same problem: users break things.

Locate and select the sheet in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), and look at your *Properties* toolwindow (F4) - notice the `Name` property matches the name that the user can change on a whim:

[image: My Awesome Sheet]

Notice also, that there's a `(Name)` property, here with a value of `Sheet1`. This is the worksheet's `CodeName`. VBA defines a global-scope object variable using that identifier, so you can do this:

```
Set inputSheet = Sheet1
```

And it will work regardless of what the user renames the sheet with.